# How to use alternating text strings in plot function

Tags: string, plot, text, pine-script

When trying to use this "text=" in my plot function:

```
plotshape(someLow,title="low", style=shape.diamond, location=location.belowbar, offset=0, text=(lowerLow ? "LL" : "HL"), color=color.green, transp=0)
```

... I get the error:

> line 77: Cannot call 'plotshape' with arguments (..., text=series[string], ...)

... because the text has to be a "const string" instead of a "series[string]"

So how can I plot alternating text (whithout repeating the whole plot function line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **label.new**
Look for it in [Pine Script Language Reference Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_label%7Bdot%7Dnew)

Try this:

```
l = label.new(bar_index, close,
     text= someLow ? "LL" : "HL")
label.delete(not lowerLow ? l: na)
```